# How to access radiobutton in RadioButtonList in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I want to change the `CssClass` for the RadioButtonList while populating the the `RadioButtonList`. I don't know how to access the radio button while binding the list. do I need to use `DataBind` or `DataBounding` event ? and how ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event as then all of the Radio Buttons will be populated.

```
Private Sub YourRadioButtonList_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles YourRadioButtonList.DataBound

    For Each rd As RadioButton In YourRadioButtonList.Items

        'Or some other condition that determines the CSS Class.
        If rd.Checked Then

            rd.CssClass = "NewCssClass"

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```